# Canoe yoke orientation: Point towards front or back?

Tags: canoes

I'm installing a yoke on a canoe that didn't have one from the factory. It only had a cross brace (the center *thwart*).

What way should I install the yoke?

A. Yoke neck hole towards the front of the canoe?
B. Yoke neck hole towards the back of the canoe?

Comment: Save yourself the pain-in-the-neck (literally) and get cushioned pad for the yoke. Level Six makes a great one with velcro straps

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to walk with the front of the boat pointing the direction you're walking. Otherwise you would paddle into a portage, and pick up the canoe -- only to find yourself facing the opposite way to how you intend to travel. You would need to turn 180 degrees to start walking the portage. Then on arrival you would have to turn around again to get the nose of the boat (bow) pointing to the water.

To skip all that, the yoke should be installed with the open part (representing you) facing forward.

Answer (score 7):

I looked up photos of canoes with yokes online.

The yokes seem to point **towards the front seat** (the *bow* seat). So I'll go with that.

---

[image]

[Source](https://paddlecamp.com/parts-of-a-canoe/)

---

[image]

[Source](https://www.clippercanoes.com/products/cascade)

---

[image]

[Source](https://bwca.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=forum.thread&threadId=116443&forumID=15&confID=1)